# Clustering but with constraint on variables

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have data containing six columns. Fist two columns contain latitude and longitudes while the other four columns contain the average monthly purchase(in kgs) of different items.
I want to cluster this dataset on the basis of latitude and longitude but with a condition the for any cluster, the sum of values corresponding to that cluster in the four columns should not exceed a given amount separately.
For example, assume that I want to select some places to locate my warehouses on the basis of the given data. But the warehouses can store a maximum of X kgs for any product type.
So, how can I perform clustering on latitude and longitude given the condition on the other four variables?

Comment: This seems like a [weighted set cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Weighted_set_cover) optimization problem which is NP-Hard.  Although, there do seem to be some approximation algorithms for it.
BTW, I don't think this is right Stack Exchange site for this kind of question.  You'll have better luck with one of the other ones.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.